# I would like to see my review audit history

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

**Confession:** I have been suspended a couple times from reviewing activities.

**Partial Redemption:** I have become better and better at passing audits.

- I'd like to see my recent and distant history with audits.
- Even better, I'd like to see my history with the various types of audits.

I'm not sure this has much value beyond self-reflection and self-analysis. I'd like to see if there are patterns to when I was more likely to fail (do I get sloppy after 10 or 20?), or if there are certain types of reviews at which I struggle more (e.g., ***suggested edit*** vs ***close question***).

I suspect that if I reviewed my history and revisited audits I failed, I could create rules and rhythms for myself to become a better reviewer.

Comment: +1 for really wanting to improve, and being willing to put in the effort to really understand your own patterns.

Comment: I think this should be a [meta-tag:feature-request], given the phrasing

Comment: You can look at your [review activity](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1212341/dave-a?tab=activity&sort=reviews) . Audits are included though there is no way to filter them.

Comment: @JoshC, I didn't realize. Will check.

Comment: @Josh The main problem is that they aren't distinguishable.

Comment: @Undo, Agreed. Looking through this list, I can't easily distinguish which are the audits.

Comment: @AsheeshR, agree about feature. I would like it. I was hoping for feed-back first. I threw my own ideas out and wanted to know if others wanted that kind of report or had other ideas.

Comment: @DaveA This is a feature request by nature. That doesn't preclude discussion about it, folks are welcome to chime in with their thoughts. A developer needs to see this to make sure it's actually feasible, though, or all of the discussion won't mount up to much. I've re-tagged accordingly.

Comment: Anyway, on the topic of your reviews, what made you approve this suggested edit? http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3467458

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, ouch, that one looks really bad! And I'm not the only sucker to fall for that one.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, to make it worse, I don't like when **suggested edits** try to alter source code. Even if I feel they improved the result, I'm unfortable with it. This is a total re-write. I definitely didn't look closely enough at this one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something that concerns me is that having these accessible through your profile somehow gives the impression that there's some sort of *permanent record* due to failing these, and there really *isn't*. Administrative actions taken by the system in `/review` are purely based on a revolving 30 day window.

I'd feel better about this (as suggested) if these were only available *from the last 30 days* (perhaps 60, but not much longer). That gives you enough to gauge where you are with it. Additionally, they should only be available for the user to view - not part of the public profile. Anything that makes people hesitant to share their profile is considered '*not a good idea (TM)*'.

I'm also not 100% certain that showing the ones you *passed* has much utility, but I can't seem to elevate much above ambivalent when it comes to that.

Just chiming in with my thoughts, I don't know if this is feasible or not - I'll leave it up to a dev to let us know on that department :)

Comment: I hear all your concerns. While I'd prefer a thorough record, a tool/report with these limitations would still be very useful. At this point we'd be arguing subtleties; Like I'd counter that while the system uses a month window, maybe I would still benefit by seeing a 2-3 month window of progression...

Comment: @DaveA I'm not opposed to a longer window, my main concern is that they just don't linger there. Your profile is (broadly) something you should feel _good_ about, as long as these drop off reasonably quickly I'm fine with it. And, of course, these should only be visible to the user.

Comment: I'd be happy with a 10-*minute* window.  Today's behavior is basically "You just failed. Why? We're not going to tell you. Please click 'I Understand.'"  That's neither revelatory nor encouraging.