# Can we please have the ability to see passed/failed audits?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audits

Ideally, I'd like the ability to see passed/failed audits on my Review History page.  If that's not possible, can we at least have some obvious denotation (even as simple as an asterisk) next to audit questions so we can find them quickly?

I know that any audit questions that are deleted are not visible in our history, and I'm fine with that.  But at times I'd like the ability to review past audits to help me understand what I did wrong, refresh that info in my brain, and use that info to make better review decisions in the future.

Comment: *I know that any audit questions that are deleted are not visible in our history, and I'm fine with that.* - but that's part of the problem. A lot of audits that you'd fail are *always* on deleted posts, like a post in LQP that you're supposed to flag. If you don't, you fail. That post would never show up in a list because it's "deleted."

Comment: Related: [I would like to see my history with AUDITS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209324/i-would-like-to-see-my-history-with-audits)

Comment: Then is there any way to keep the deleted posts if they've been used as an audit?  Just mark them some way in the DB so they stick around but don't show up on the site anywhere else?  I'm not really sure how audits are determined so that may not be possible/practical.

Comment: @JohnnyBones (almost) nothing is hard deleted, so to keep it around is not the issue.  The issue is just making it visible to you

Comment: Are the same questions used as audits multiple times, or is it a one-shot deal?  If they're used multiple times, you can probably just mark it with an "A" or something in a new column, and then when it displays in a user's history it can either show up with that "A" or with an asterisk or something.  If not, then maybe you have a new table with audit question numbers, which userID it was given to, and their pass/fail status, and then join that to the rest of the user's history.  Either way it's a bit of work, but I think it would be helpful.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I don't really know the underlying mechanics, but audits are generated from recent questions that meet specific criteria, so a specific question is unlikely to be used more than once unless it happens to get selected twice (and my guess is it is either not allowed or so rare bordering on impossible)