# Could you at least give me a hint, what recent audits I've failed?

Tags: support, review, review-audits, review-suspension

It happens sometimes. I've met an answer in first posts queue, which was not very good formated, but tried to diagnose the OPs problem as the bug in some library. I can't say if it's correct or not, but the review audits are not for testing the answer validity - the votes do. I've thought because it may help the OP, it should be accepted. Apparently it shouldn't. Now I got a message

> #### You have failed too many recent review audits – looks like you might need a break. Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing.

I have now a little WTF feeling, because I can't remember any **recently** failed audit except that single one. Surely there was none today. Maybe there was some yeasterday, but I can't remember any. I can remember **passing** quite a few audits.

OK, I have that message so at least I'd like to know how many audits were "too many" and what is "recently". Can I see at least some statistics about review audits passed/failed?

Comment: In case it helps, I think the audit failure that triggered the final ban was this: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4177965 , but there might be others. Even for moderators, this can be a bit tricky to sort out, which is why I asked for this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199218/moderators-should-have-easy-access-to-a-users-complete-review-history-includin . Unfortunately, audits on deleted posts like the above don't show in the normal list.

Comment: @BradLarson yes, that's what triggered it. In spite of fact that I think the answer contains **some** useful info, so it should be rather converted to comment, I'd like to find out what else was there. AFAIK any single audit can't trigger review ban alone.

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to in the comments in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209671/can-we-please-have-the-ability-to-see-passed-failed-audits) (see comments by Animuson and Psubsee2003), apparently the audit questions are likely questions that either were deleted or were in the process of being deleted.  Whichever the case, the gist is that the audit questions were no longer available and couldn't be viewed.

I do concur that having them available would be convenient, but at the current time that's just not possible.

Comment: Yes, I've found that question, but it isn't helpful to me. I want to know how many audits I've failed, not how they are stored in DB.