# How should I approach an obvious review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I recently reviewed a late answer that looked suspiciously like an audit (and passed I guess?)

After my review (I commented, then clicked "I'm done") it doesn't show up in my review history.  I assume then that I was correct and this was an audit.

My question is:  what should I do, as a reviewer, when I think that I am obviously being audited?

I will say that while my review wasn't different from what I would have done if I never thought it was an audit, I did spend more time thinking about it and second-guessing myself.  In the end though, I didn't pad or fluff anything and gave my honest opinion in the review.

As an aside, is there a way to see audit history?

Comment: No way at the moment, there's a [pending feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209324/i-would-like-to-see-my-history-with-audits)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it was an audit, it would have told you it was an audit when you attempted to do something. If it let you post a comment and click I'm Done and gave you no notification, then it wasn't an audit. If it's not appearing in your history, then it's likely since been deleted. Deleted posts do not show up in your activity, and previous activity that gets deleted later on eventually gets removed from your activity.

Past that, if you can blatantly tell that something is an audit, review it. There's nothing else you need to do and no special approach to it.

Currently, review audits will show up in your review history like any other review item (they're not marked in any way that they were audits). But again, deleted posts *don't show up* and since a lot of review audits in that queue will be deleted posts, they'll never appear in your activity.

Comment: Well, they do appear in the review history available for 10k users even for deleted posts.

Comment: @Shadow Yes, the history tab in the review queue itself will show all reviews regardless (although I'm not 100% sure if the deleted posts are limited to 10k users). I was talking about the activity history on the user's profile, simply because that's where I always look since the history tab is always cluttered with other people's reviews.

Comment: I just checked and the answer, indeed, has been deleted.  It must have been deleted while I was reviewing, because it never showed in history.  Glad to know that there is a blatant clue (after the audit)